# Execute command if another is successful and log stdout and stderr to file in bash

Tags: bash

I have two commands, let's call them **command1** and **command2**.
What I need to do is:

- have command 2 execute only if command 1 is successful
- have stdout and stderr of both commands redirected to a file, let's call it log.txt

How would I write it in bash in a way that's simple to understand later?

Answer (score 7):

I guess that you want

```
( command1  &&  command2 )   >&   /tmp/log.txt
```

the `>&` [is](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Output) a `bash`ism (also exists in `zsh`) to redirect both stderr and stdout

the parenthesis create a subshell by [grouping commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping).

<sup>(to put that in the background, add a `&` at end of line, after final `.txt` )</sup>

Comment: Long version: `command1 >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1 && command2 >>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: What if I wanted the whole thing to execute in the background? Would it be as simple as adding a '&' at the end, or would that screw up the output redirection?

Comment: That will work fine; redirections are associated with a single command, but `&` terminates an entire *list*, which can be comprised of multiple commands.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap {}'s around a block of code to redirect all its i/o. You can stack all the code you want collectively handled, or keep it short and sweet.

Use && to execute a following command only if the previous command succeeded.
( Use || to execute a following command only if the previous command *failed*. )
This lets you set up if/then/else structures without much additional syntax.

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2; } >log.txt 2>&1
```

But if you want it to be really easy to understand later, maybe even to someone less familiar with bash, you can collect all the output from an actual if/then/elif/else structure too -

```
if cmd1          # if cmd1 succeeds
then cmd2        # then run cmd2
fi >log.txt 2>&1 # 2>&1 send stderr where stdout went
```

Don't underestimate the value of keeping it simple...or of adding ***comments***.